# Pulp: Adding multiple LpSum in a loop

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have a list like:

```
list = [var_1, var_2, var_3]
```

Using Pulp library, I'm trying to define them as variables with a for loop doing:

```
LpVariable(list[i] for i in range(len(list)))
```

Then I'm trying to sum them all and asign it to the model:

```
model += LpVariable(list[i] for i in range(len(list)))
```

In both cases I'm getting an error that says **expected string or bytes-like object**

Can anyone help me?

Regards

Comment: I guess the closing bracket ] at the end of the second and third line should be a closing parantheses ), right? What exactly are you trying to achieve with list[i] for i in range(len(list))? Not sure what this LpVariable is, but it seems it to demand a string or bytes-like object as input. You provide a generator.

Comment: The ] at the end it was a typo. In Pulp library, you have to define the variables for linear programming and that must be done with de LpVariable object.

Comment: What is var_1, etc? Are these strings? The first parameter of Lpvariable should be its name (i.e. a string). If you want to index a bunch of variables use a list, a dict or PuLP's LpVariable.dicts.

Comment: I'd recommend against calling a variable `list` or any other built-in type name or python keyword. Python will not throw an error but it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id did not check the syntax but lpSum can sum a list of LpVariables so do you want something that looks more like

```
model += LpSum([LpVariable(i) for i in list])
```

this assumes that the elements of your list are name strings and you want to create new LpVariables.

if so, you may want to  first save these new LpVariables in a list or dict so you can use them in constraints and then add them as a objective to the model

if the elements of your list are already LpVariables then you just need

```
model += LpSum(list)
```